# best practice: should i unbind on custom widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

i create custom multiple span element and bind with with click event.  i want to dynamically remove the span on click. i can just remove the span with remove() function. for good practice, should i call unbind on the span first before call remove() ? please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/remove/), calling `remove` will automatically unbind the click event. So you should be okay.